# Disable a link in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm attempting to disable a link until an API call is made in Angular 6. I want the link to be disabled until the getSelectedDealer() API is returned.

```
 <menu-link *ngIf="perms.has(perms.TOP_OFFERS) && _dealerPersistenceService.getSelectedDealer()"
           route="/dynamic-journeys/{{getDealerId()}}/vehicles">
    <menu-item><img src="/assets/menu-icons/top-offers.svg">Dynamic Journeys</menu-item>
</menu-link>
```

Here is the code for the 'a' tag component and the CSS.

```
<a [routerLink]="route" routerLinkActive="active" class="menu-link" [class.disabled]="disabled ? true: null">
<ng-content select="menu-item"></ng-content>
```

```
a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Basically I need the 'menu-link' items to be disabled prior to API call and be enabled after.

Comment: `<a [routerLink]="route" routerLinkActive="active" class="menu-link" [disabled]="apiReturned ? true : false " >`. With `apiReturned` as a component property??

Comment: Just set the `disabled` flag to `true` by default. And reset it to the value you want upon the return of the `API` call.

Comment: Disabled property doesn't exist on 'a' tag by default. Do I set the toggle flag for disabled on the underlying 'a' tag or in the menu-link?

Comment: @LDB: Sorry, didn't realize it was an anchor, even though I have added an answer, why is your approach not working??

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to have the link disabled until the _dealerPersistenceService.getSelectedDealer() is returned. This method is in the menu-link component and not in the underlying 'a' tag. Can I check that this method has been called and returned in the underlying 'a' tag or do I place it in the menu-link?

Comment: @LDB: The component in which your `anchor` tag resides lets  say `anchorTag` component, it `anchorTag` component a child component of `menu-link` component?

Comment: As you can see the 'a' tag has a class of 'menu-link' which is being used as the 'a' tag. The 'menu-link' is hidden unless the '_dealerPersistenceService.getSelectedDealer()' method has been returned. Instead of hiding the 'menu-link' until the API is returned... I simply want to have the 'menu-link' shown however it needs to be disabled.

Comment: Will see this in a while..

Comment: @LDB: Sorry for the late response, you can see the edited answer of mine..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use  no matter what, you could achieve that by simply add click event to this link with something like that:

```
<a [routerLink]="route"
   routerLinkActive="active"
   class="menu-link"
   [class.disabled]="disabled ? true: null"
   (click)="check($event)">
```

**In TS:**

```
isReady = false;
check = (event) => {
 if (!this.isReady) {
   event.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

So isReady is a boolean variable of your component, and it is false until you want to. When ever you click this link, it will check if it is true, but if it is false, it will prevent the original behavior of the event, and nothing will fire.

Answer (score 5):

Angular needs a way to selectively apply directives, but here was my solution:

```
<a
    (click)="markAsRead(notification);notification.externalUrl || $event.preventDefault()"
    [href]="notification.externalUrl"
    target="_blank""
...>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your component have a flag which tells whether the API has returned..:

```
apiReturned = false;

ngOnInit() {

   setTimeout(() => {
      // simulating API call, sets to true after 5 seconds
      this.apiReturned = true;
   }, 5000);
}
```

And have your HTML like:

```
 <a [class.disabled]="apiReturned ? null: true"  [href]="apiReturned ? 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/9442497/ldb' : null" >Click Me!</a>
```

Here I have also removed the `href` from the `anchor` when it is supposed to be disabled.

**EDIT**

If your anchor tag resides in a different component, then you have two ways to perform the task.

1. Send the Route and the API's status to the `mat-link` component and act accordingly
2. Have a service which takes the value of API status from the parent component and use the service's data in `mat-link` component. I would prefer using a service because you will also have to block the route from the URL bar when the API has not returned, using Input you can only block the link, but that will not help if someone directly enters the route url in the URL bar. You can use Angular's `Route Guard` to prevent routing in such cases

I will explain the usage of the first way and leave the second way for you to implement.

In your `mat-link` component.ts, have something like:

```
export class MatLinkComponent  {
  @Input() route: string;
  @Input() apiReturned: boolean;
}
```

And in your `mat-link.component.html`, have something like:

```
<a *ngIf="!apiReturned" href="#" [class.disabled]="!apiReturned" >Click Me!</a>

<a *ngIf="apiReturned" [routerLink]="route" routerLinkActive="active" >Click Me!</a>
```

You could notice that I have created two `anchor` tags which are conditional, this is because, `routerlink` won't accept `null` and we don't have something like conditional `routerLink` yet.

In the parent component, say `app.component.html` or wherever you are using `mat-link.component`, have something like:

```
<mat-link 
      [apiReturned]=apiReturned
      [route]="'routinghere'">
</mat-link>
```

You can See a working example here: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3endd). The `Click Me!` link will activate after 10 seconds..

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ok I tried this. Right now every link is disabled as if apiReturned=false. The api that is called is _dealerPersistenceService.getSelectedDealer() ... As you can see in my code above the menu-link is hidden until this call is made. How do I switch to apiReturned =true 'a' tag once the call is made?

Comment: Where ever you are making the API call, say here you will be making in the `App` componenet.. So, if your service is returning an `Observable`, you can do something like: `_dealerPersistenceService.getSelectedDealer().subscribe((success)=>{// check success and then this.apiReturned = true })`

Comment: The API call is not an observable

Comment: @LDB: then? Is it a promise? Or are you subscribing in the service itself?

Comment: This method is being called in the .ts file for the menu-link component. The method looks like this                                                                          
 getDealerId() {
        return this._dealerPersistenceService.getSelectedDealer().id;
    } . Can I not just toggle the apiReturned property here? It doesn't seem that I can given the property exists on the child component 'a' tag

Comment: @LDB: So, when do you call that method? Set the apiReturned flag to true wherever you are calling `getDealerId()`

Comment: This is what I've tried.. However how do I get access to the API boolean in the component where the method is called?? The property(apiReturned) is created in the "matlinkComponent"(which is the child component). I need to toggle this boolean in the parent component that calls the method...

Comment: @LDB: `apiReturned` is a property of both paarent and the child. At the very first. It is a property of the parent and then sent as a input property to the child i.e. mat-link. Didn&#39;t you open the link which I have added in the answer as &quot;Example&quot;? You will see that I am toggling the flag in the parent itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's achievable as per your needs. Suppose you are using component you can create a service object. Use it in the component where you want to enable/disable a href. Otherwise as mentioned by above answers. If you want don't want to use prevent default you can simple return false.

```
    check($event){
     return false;
    }
```